# ImageButton background is not changed when it is selected

Tags: android, background, selector, imagebutton

I am having a ImageButton and when I press it, Its background/src should be changed i have created a selector for it but it doesn't seem to be working.

can anyone tell me why it is not working.

**navigation_button_drawable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <bitmap android:antialias="true" android:src="@drawable/t_navigation_dw" />
            </item>
            <item>
                <bitmap android:gravity="left" android:src="@drawable/left_padding" android:tileMode="disabled" />
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item  android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <bitmap android:src="@drawable/t_navigation_dw" />
            </item>
            <item>
                <bitmap android:gravity="left" android:src="@drawable/left_padding" android:tileMode="disabled" />
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/t_navigation_up">
    </item>
</selector>
```

ImageButton initialization in layout xml.

```
 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/navigation_image_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/navigation_button_drawable" />
```

Comment: you are not setting seletor xml file to the `ImageButton` set `android:background="@drawable/navigation_image_button_selector"`

Comment: I am and its working fine but when I leave the finger from button it goes again to its previous state, I want it to be selected.

Comment: Mean it if it clicked once it must be remain selected.?

Comment: you need to do `imageView.setSelected()` after clicking that `ImageView`.

Answer (score 2):

You are not setting seletor xml file to the `ImageButton` set

Replace

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

with

```
android:background="@drawable/navigation_image_button_selector"
```

To keep selected

inside the `onClick` of the `ImageView` call `view.setSelected(true);` 

in order to force the content of the `ImageView` to change.